# Do you ever feel indebted to someone who started your career?

Tags: career-development, careers

It's been 2 years now since I got the career I really want. I don't know how I got hired. I just copied what others' strategy was before like creating something and showing the employer. I got a mobile app and a blog back then. I like to think that is the reason I got hired.

I was kind of happy until recently, I was made aware by some people that my remuneration package was lower than other people and found out that the same people who hired me do not really kind of see me as a highly technical person. Keep in mind though that this person is really skilled at technical stuff. They were in the field for a long time probably after they graduated at some university.

I, on the other hand, have been out of the field for almost a decade. I only made it because of hard work. I am aware that for me it takes time to learn something hence I always relying on hard work spending more time to understand things than other people even doing over time just to finish my task. It kind of hurt a little when I found that out and get the feeling that it will be a hard battle to get promoted or get more pay from my company because of that.

Then I found out that some of the comments towards me from higher management is that I started late in my career which is true; I started my career at 30. I feel like it's an issue for them. They were probably thinking it's the reason I am not technically skilled enough due to lack of experience. I also found out that a lot of new hires who were on the same level as I am got paid more compared to people who had been in my company for longer. I found that out on a GlassDoor review and by asking some people who left.

Now I am torn. I have an upcoming interview and I'm thinking about whether I should cancel it or purposefully bomb the interview. I feel indebted to the people who hired me. I just can't shake the feeling that if I have not been hired by this company, none of my interviews would have happened and that I would still be in a low paying factory job I despise. I mean these people who hired me knew that I had a huge gap and late getting started on my career yet they still hired me.

I can't decide. On one hand I am really grateful for the opportunity they had given me; on the other hand, I should also be thinking for my self and my future and I really doubt they will give me a counter offer base on their judgement of my skill. I don't know it's hard. Any advice would really help.

Comment: No, but I do feel indebted to the person that invented paragraphs.

Comment: Why do you feel indebted to a company who isn’t paying you what you feel you are worth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know how I got hired. I just copied what others strategy was before like creating something and showing to employer. I got a mobile app and a blog back then. I like to think that's is the reason I got hired.

You got hired because you demonstrated that you can build an app and blog about your experience - those are valuable skills that by all means make you a good candidate. Don't downplay your hard work that got you this job: companies don't hire people out of mercy, they hire people they believe can do the job.

> I was made by some people aware that my remuneration package was lower than other people and found out that the same people who hired me does not really kind of see me as a highly technical person.

None of this matters: until you become the company's CEO you remuneration package will likely always be lower than somebody else's. What people who hired you think also doesn't matter. What's important is what your direct manager thinks about the work that you do, and that you know what your personal compensation expectations are, and whether what you're currently earning is above or below that.

> Then I found out that some of the comments towards me from higher management is that I started late on my career which is true, I started my career at 30, I feel like its an issue for them, they were probably thinking its the reason I am not technically skilled enough due to lack of experience.

Again, this doesn't matter, focus on doing a good job and proving them wrong.

> I also found out that a lot of new hires who were on the same level as I am got paid more compared to people who had been on my company for longer.

Unfortunately this is how things work, especially in the tech field. When you were hired the market rate was X, after two years the market rate is X + 20%. The company won't be able to hire anybody for X anymore, so the new hires get X + 20%. Meanwhile, it's very likely that most of the current staff won't get a 20% raise. The only surefire way to earn market rate in this kind of field is to change jobs often.

> I feel indebted to the people who hired me.

Don't be, you got to where you are thanks to your hard work.

> ...I should also be thinking for my self and my future...

Exactly. If a better opportunity presents itself - take it. Thank your employer for giving you a chance, give them a proper notice and leave on good terms.

Answer (score 2):

We all have to do what is in our own best interests.

You got the work you wanted, that's great. In return your employer got work out of you. Now you have been made aware that more recently they have been getting this work out of you at a discount.

You aren't an indentured servant. Go find a new job, and when you get one thank your current employer for taking a chance on you and move on.